# can you plz help solve this bone flickering?

Tags: rigging

can you plz help solve this bone flickering ?

pivot not moving along with the end effector. can you pl tell me why it is so ?

plz see in the video..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNsH8WvM3ps

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You have disconnected but you need to unparent, otherwise there's a circular dependency

Comment: Thanks very much moonboots for your guidance